# Record Vidochat in pubnub

Tags: javascript, android, web, webrtc, pubnub

I'm using pubnub for videochat,I'm using https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-10-13-build-android-webrtc-video-voice-chat-app/ sample code for doing this.I want to record that video conversion,Can any one help me to resolve my Issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Recording is somewhat complicated. You first need to decide if the recording will be done locally or remotely.

- Local recording on a smartphone is something you should do only inside an app, and only when the session is short as storage space is limited
- Local recording on a desktop browser is trickier, as you don't even know how much storage space is available. Limit such sessions to a few minutes only
- Remote recording is the way to go most of the time, though there's a slight drop in quality due to packet losses that might occur in the network. For this one, look at Kurento (http://www.kurento.org) as something that can get you there

You can check more about these alternatives here: https://bloggeek.me/recording-webrtc-sessions/

Comment: Is it possible with twilio?

Comment: AFAIK, PubNub and Twilio act as the *signal protocol* for video/audio apps and do not store the media. You need a storage service to do that, like Box, Amazon S3, etc.

Comment: Twilio offers recording capabilities for the audio out of the box. If you need video, then look at TokBox.